# Deploy prestashop store errors

Tags: prestashop

I created a prestashop store in my development server.
After completion, to copy it to the final server and after changing the settings of the database and the domain, the site does not open in ie, ff, chrome and safari (but, if I view the source code in the browsers, he is corrects), only opens the opera. appear in other browsers the following errors:

**in chrome:**

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 67 at column 95: EntityRef: expecting ';'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

**in firefox:**

```
Error in analise the XML: bad formater
Location: http://douradoedourado.pt/
Line number 78, colune 191:$('#logofont').change(function(){var gFontVal=$("option:selected",this).val();var gFontName=gFontVal.split(':');$.cookie("logo_font",gFontVal);if($('head').find('link#logofont_link').length<1){$('head').append('<link id="logofont_link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />');}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we move PS site to another server, we got some problems with it. To fix them please do the followings: 
**Note: These points may or may not fix the issues you have.**

1) Disable cache and enable force compile.

2) Delete all compiled files from the cache/smarty/compile and also the cache/smarty/cache folder contents if there are any except index.php

3) Check the settings for the site url and ssl urls.

4) Regenerate .htaccess file

After these, check the site.

If the site does not open, then enable errors like below

open file in config/defines.inc.php and set _PS_MODE_DEV to true to enable errors.

After that reload the page. You will see errors. If you still dont understand those errors, then update your post along with the errors contents, and then i may be able to help you.

Thank you

Comment: thx for reply. unfortunately did not fix any issue. it generates the same error